# If a location name (NOT id) is changed, will it update in the form data?

Tags: commcare

In this project's scenario, we have supervisors as one organization level, and each of the supervisors has 9 to 11 child CHW locations. For ease for our partner's form exports, we named the locations the name of the CHW mobile worker that is assigned to that location.

In form exports, I know we can include the location name as well as the mobile user that submitted the form. My question is: if we update the name of the location because a new CHW needs to take over the cases and the old CHW no longer works on the project, does the location name update in the form data exports? So if CHW1 is the name of the location, and forms are submitted, but then the next month CHW1 quits and CHW2 takes their cases and we change the name (NOT id) of the location, in teh form exports, will the the "location" field stay as what it was when the forms were submitted, or update to say "CHW2"?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a good idea to test this out to be sure, but my understanding is that it will reflect the current name of the location.  I'd have to check to be certain, but my guess is that forms store the id of the user that submitted them, and then the location is looked up when the export is prepared.
This would also mean that if the user is assigned to a different location, the form would travel with them, and an export would display the user's current location's current name.